# Progress bar value not bound to data-bind value attribute using Knockout.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have a progress bar, and I added a condition that, if the value is below 100, the color should be red; and if it is 100, the color should change to green. But when I debug the code I see the progress value return 0 even if some value is assigned to value attribute.

Below is the progress bar code, and I am assigning value 100 within the `data-bind` attribute.

```html
<div class="card-header float-right" style="width:50%; padding-left:100px;">
  <progress id="myProgress" data-bind="attr: { value: 100, }" min="0" max="100"></progress>
</div>
```

Below is the javascript code; when I debug and check progress value, it displays 0.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var progressvalue = $("#myProgress").val();
    var progressText = $("#myProgress").text();
    if (progressvalue == 100) {
        $('#myProgress').addClass("progress-100");
        $('#myProgress').removeClass("progress-below");
    }
    else {
        $('#myProgress').addClass("progress-below");
        $('#myProgress').removeClass("progress-100");
    }
});
```

Comment: Do you have a typo in ```onload="chnagecolor()"```?  BTW, what does this function look like?

Comment: yes that is a typo. I am glad you noticed.

Comment: How are you updating the ```value``` attribute in your code?  BTW, ```min``` is not needed for ```<progress>``` element, since it is always 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need the `data-bind` attribute from what I can see in your current code (though you may have a reason outside of what you've shown).  **Edit:** For Knockout.js, you will of course need the `data-bind` attribute.

All you need to do is set a `value` for your [`<progress>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/progress) element, and then make sure you're updating it [as whatever process it represents is progressing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ProgressEvent).

```html
<progress id="myProgress" value="10" max="100"></progress>
```

**Edit:**
For [Knockout.js](https://knockoutjs.com/), you need to tie your [`data-bind`](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-syntax.html) attributes to a [ViewModel](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html#mvvm_and_view_models) field, and that ViewModel field would need to be associated with an Observable.

You could do something like this (a toy example that just increments the progress value by 10 each second, but shows how you could update your ViewModel, as well as trigger a class change after reaching a threshold value):

```html
<div class="card-header float-right" style="width:50% ; padding-left:100px">
<progress
      id="myProgress"
      data-bind="value: progressValue, class: progressClass"
      max="100"
></progress>
</div>

<script>
      const INITIAL_PROGRESS = 1;
      const PROGRESS_THRESHOLD = 90;
      const BELOW_THRESHOLD_CLASS = "progress-below";
      const ABOVE_THRESHOLD_CLASS = "progress-100";

      let progressViewModel = {
        progressValue: ko.observable(INITIAL_PROGRESS),
        progressClass: ko.observable(BELOW_THRESHOLD_CLASS)
      };

      ko.applyBindings(
        progressViewModel,
        document.getElementById("myProgress")
      );

      ko.when(
        function() {
          return progressViewModel.progressValue() > PROGRESS_THRESHOLD;
        },
        function(result) {
          progressViewModel.progressClass(ABOVE_THRESHOLD_CLASS);
        }
      );

      for (let i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
        window.setTimeout(function() {
          progressViewModel.progressValue(i * 10);
        }, i * 1000);
      }

</script>
```

Then you have to figure out how you want your Observable value(s) updated.

Comment: Thanks this is working fine. But I am using knockout.js and this value is going to be dynamic, In that case what should I do?

Comment: Please see edits to further assist with Knockout.js specific code.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using KnockoutJS, the actual progress is probably an observable property on your viewmodel. Let's say it is actually called `progress`, then you would bind to it like this:

```
<div class="card-header float-right" style="width:50% ; padding-left:100px">
    <progress id="myProgress" data-bind="attr: { value: progress }" min="0" max="100"></progress>
</div>
```

For styling, you should use the `css` or `class` bindings to assign a class to the progress bar, based on the progress. Here's a Fiddle with a little example, although I've used the Bootstrap progress element and not the actual native progress element since it's a nightmare to style: https://jsfiddle.net/thebluenile/20zsqn5w/